How to Use MERGE INTO with Views in PostgreSQL
I am currently working with PostgreSQL, which does not support SYNONYM, so I created a VIEW as a workaround. While I can successfully use UPDATE and INSERT operations on this view, I encountered an issue when trying to use the MERGE INTO ... UPDATE/INSERT command.
It appears that MERGE operations are not supported on views in PostgreSQL.
Has anyone faced this problem before? What would be an effective way to work around this limitation to enable similar MERGE functionality with views? Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Why don't you MERGE into the underlying table rather than into the view?

MERGE will work on updatable views in Postgres 17+.

What version do you use, and what is the DDL for the tables and view(-s)?

Thank you , I will be waiting for the v17 to be cluded on my AWS server !
